# Getting Class App\Http\Controllers\PostController does not exist error in Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting these errors when I try to create new post:

> 2/2 ReflectionException in Route.php line 280:
>   Class App\Http\Controllers\PostController does not exist
>
> 1/2 FatalThrowableError in PostController.php line 70:
>   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Session' (T_STRING)

Everything worked fine until I added this line of code in the `store()` method:

```
$post->tags()->sync($request->tags, false);
```

Here is my controller

```
<?php
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

 use App\Category;
 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
 use App\Http\Requests;
 use App\Post;
 use App\Tag;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use Session;

 class PostController extends Controller
 {
   public function __construct()
   {
      $this->middleware('auth');
   }

   public function index()
   {
      $posts = Post::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);
      return view('posts.index')->withPosts($posts);
   }

   public function create()
   {
      $categories = Category::pluck('name', 'id');
      $tags = Tag::pluck('name', 'id');
      return view('posts.create', compact('categories', 'tags'));
   }

   public function store(Request $request)
   {
      $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required|max:255',
            'slug'  => 
            'required|alpha_dash|min:5|max:255|unique:posts,slug',
            'category_id' => 'required|integer',
            'body'  => 'required'
        ]);

       $post = new Post;

       $post->title = $request->title;
       $post->slug = $request->slug;
       $post->category_id = $request->category_id;
       $post->body = $request->body;

       $post->save();

       $post->tags()->sync($request->tags, false);

       Session::flash('success', 'The blog post was successfully save!');

       return redirect()->route('posts.show', $post->id);
    }

  public function show($id)
  {
       $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
       return view('posts.show', compact('post'));
  }


  public function edit($id)
  {
      $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
      $categories = Category::pluck('name', 'id');
      return view('posts.edit', compact('post', 'categories'));
  }

  public function update(Request $request, $id)
  {
      $post = Post::find($id);
      if ($request->input('slug') == $post->slug) {
        $this->validate($request, array(
            'title' => 'required|max:255',
            'category_id' => 'required|integer',
            'body'  => 'required'
        ));
      } else {
        $this->validate($request, array(
            'title' => 'required|max:255',
            'slug'  => 
            'required|alpha_dash|min:5|max:255|unique:posts,slug',
            'category_id' => 'required|integer',
            'body'  => 'required'
        ));
    }

          $post = Post::find($id);

          $post->title = $request->input('title');
          $post->slug = $request->input('slug');
          $post->category_id = $request->input('category_id');
          $post->body = $request->input('body');

          $post->save();

         Session::flash('success', 'This post was successfully saved.');

         redirect with flash data to posts.show
         return redirect()->route('posts.show', $post->id);
     }

     public function destroy($id)
     {
        $post = Post::find($id);

        $post->delete();

        Session::flash('success', 'The post was successfully deleted.');
        return redirect()->route('posts.index');
     }
   }
```

Comment: You have a syntax error right below Session::flash in your update method.

Comment: that is just comment

Comment: A comment that's not commented out, unless it's a copy/paste mistake.

Comment: It's a copy paste mistake. In my controller it's commented

Comment: Can you post your tags model? Also, which line is line 70? The error does not match the line numbers of the code you posted.

Comment: line 70 is in store method on Session::flash line.  Here is Tag model  <?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tag extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post');
    }
}

Comment: You have an invisible character: `$post->tags()->sync($request->tags, false);<feff>`. Delete the line and try typing it again.

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot! But, how did you know that it was invisible character? I just did what you told me and it worked.

Comment: Luckily the character was in the code pasted here. I pasted it into my IDE, which told me there was a syntax error but not why. So I opened the file in vim, which showed me that character.

Comment: @aynber If you want post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an invisible character:

```
$post->tags()->sync($request->tags, false);<feff>
```

If your editor has a way to view non-printable characters, that might show characters like this.